# Inset text effect works on Chrome, but not on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/xmev9pbv/1/), which works nicely in Chrome:

[image: Chrome example]

but in Firefox, it won't, as you see here:

[image: Firefox example]

The actual CSS to focus on is this:

```
.inset-text-effect {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 50px 50px 100px / 0 100px;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 100px / 0 100px;
  font: normal 70px/1 "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(48,48,48,1);
  text-align: justify;
  text-transform: normal;
  text-indent: 44%;
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  white-space: pre;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0, rgba(0,0,0,1) 4%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 67%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 68%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0, rgba(0,0,0,1) 4%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 67%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 68%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0, rgba(0,0,0,1) 4%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 67%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 68%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-background-size: auto auto;
  background-size: auto auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.5) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 9px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.5) inset;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(140,140,140,0.6) , -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.67) ;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-25.21014298575622deg) rotateY(-38.38deg) rotateZ(-18.0535228296deg)   ;
  transform: rotateX(-25.21014298575622deg) rotateY(-38.38deg) rotateZ(-18.0535228296deg)   ;
}
```

Full snippet:

```css
body {
  background: #3fa46a;
}
.inset-text-effect {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 100px / 0 100px;
  font: normal 70px/1"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(48, 48, 48, 1);
  text-align: justify;
  text-transform: normal;
  text-indent: 44%;
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  white-space: pre;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 67%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 68%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 67%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 68%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 67%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 68%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-size: auto auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 9px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.6), -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
  transform: rotateX(-25.21014298575622deg) rotateY(-38.38deg) rotateZ(-18.0535228296deg);
}
```

```html
<nav class="cl-effect-9">
  <div class="inset-text-effect">iCage</div>
</nav>
```

The CSS is auto generated from [enjoycss](http://enjoycss.com/start#text).

Comment: [Use `padding-left` instead of `text-indent`](http://jsfiddle.net/94L6LwL7/). It seems that the text-indent isn't being contained with Firefox. Not sure which behaviour is correct.

Comment: Aside: [Are you aware that using Comic Sans is a criminal offense?](http://www.comicsanscriminal.com/)

Comment: @misterManSam your comments are great, I will go to jail and I will change it! :D Your edit was great, I think you should answer my question, will you please? :) Moreover, it would be nice if you suggest an alternative to my crime, because the site you linked to, doesn't!

Comment: Use [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) to find a typeface :) There is a "handwriting" filter which may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @misterManSam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem and solution

Firefox is not containing the `text-indent`, so use `padding-left` instead.

---

### Other thoughts

The auto-generated CSS has a few prefixed properties. To see if these are necessary, check the browser compatibility of any CSS properties over on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com). Also, [using Comic Sans is a criminal offense](http://www.comicsanscriminal.com/)!

---

#### Example

```css
body {
  background: #3fa46a;
}
.inset-text-effect {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 100px / 0 100px;
  font: normal 70px/1"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(48, 48, 48, 1);
  text-align: justify;
  text-transform: normal;
  padding-left: 44%;
  text-overflow: clip;
  white-space: pre;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 67%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 68%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 67%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 68%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 67%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 68%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-size: auto auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 9px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.6), -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
  transform: rotateX(-25.21014298575622deg) rotateY(-38.38deg) rotateZ(-18.0535228296deg);
}
```

```html
<nav class="cl-effect-9">
  <div class="inset-text-effect">iCage</div>
</nav>
```